# Conexion base de datos nube azure con proyecto visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql

Estoy tratando de conectar un proyecto mvc5 visual studio, con la base de datos SQL server esta base de datos la subi en un servidor en azure. El proyecto maneja 2 tipos de conecciones 
 add name="CONNECTION-A" connectionString="server=XXX;database=YYY;user id=XXX;password=BBB"

add name="CONNECTION-B" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ZZZZ.ssdl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=YYY;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=AAA;Password=BBBB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

XXX is the server (MSSQL host)
YYY is the database name
AAA is the database user, and
BBB is the user password.
(ZZZZ is a pipe-delimited list of something)

la conección a me anda a la perfeción la b me da error

en mi proyecto local tengo de esta forma la conexion B
add name="FNSOFTContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EDM.FNSOFTContext.csdl|res://*/EDM.FNSOFTContext.ssdl|res://*/EDM.FNSOFTContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=TOVIR\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=FNSOFT;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

tambien no comprendo que se refiere con (ZZZZ is a pipe-delimited list of something)

Comment: ¿Cuál mensaje de error recibes conectándote vía conexión B? Tu segunda conexión (B) esta mirando a una base de datos en tu PC, ¿no quieres hacer que apunte a una base de datos en Azure SQL también?

Comment: Este es el mensaje de Error https://i.ibb.co/FVwkq4z/123.png

Comment: conectándome locamente no hay ningún problema  localmente tengo 1 sola base de datos, con 3 conecciones son las siguientes https://i.ibb.co/19Kp8LZ/1234.png

Comment: al configurar conectandolas a la base de datos subida en azure las 2 primeras me andan perfectamente pero al entrar al modulo que interactua me da el error que ya emncione antes asi esta maso la conexion de la nube https://i.ibb.co/XDfNKh0/123456.png

Comment: El string de conexion FNSOFT no esta bien. Prueba connectionString="Data Source=.TOVIR\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=FNSOFT;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"